# Optocoupler voltage drop when connected to load

Tags: opto-isolator, isolation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feEcZc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The inverter supplies max 25mA. 
The optocoupler draws 18mA. 
The optocoupler is supplying 1.7V to the sensor at node 1 instead of close to 5V. When I disconnect the sensor, the output voltage is 4.7V. I need at least 3.3V to power the sensor. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Refer: [Sensor datasheet](https://global.sharp/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/gp2y0a21yk_e.pdf)
[Optocoupler datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/HCPL-4504-Avago-datasheet-7564009.pdf)

Comment: What is the sensor? Link to datasheet? Pop them into the question using the edit link. How much current does it require? How much will it get when fed via a 1k resistor, R3?

Comment: Thanks for the sensor link. I can't find that opto-coupler and it looks unusual. Can you add a datasheet link for that too?

Comment: The optocoupler isn't supplying voltage to the sensor, your 5 V supply is. But it's doing it through a 1 kohm resistor. Whatever current *I* your sensor draws, the voltage on its supply node is going to be \$5\ V - I(1\ k\Omega)\$.

Comment: @Transistor, I read the opto part number as HCPL4504. I found it easily with a Google search, available from Mouser and other usual places.

Comment: Yeah, it's not very clear what you're intending to do here – you're connecting your senson'rs supply  to something with a source impedance of at least 1kΩ. How and why did you come up with this circuit? I'd say it works as expected.

Comment: Also, LM358 and single-ended 5V supply? sounds like a baaaaad idea.

Comment: So, please explain *why* your circuit is like it is, what you want to achieve with the way you connected the sensor to the octocoupler, and why it's connected to the octocoupler at all..

Comment: I wish to control the sensor on/off with the DSPACE but it only supplies a limited current so i used the optocoupler to isolate. 

The circuitry connected to the output of the sensor is a 2nd order butterworth lpf

Comment: @Simon, the output current of the opto will be **less** than the LED current. Google *high-side switch* or *low-side switch* for lots of examples of more common ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The [sensor datasheet](https://global.sharp/products/device/lineup/data/pdf/datasheet/gp2y0a21yk_e.pdf) says it requires 30 mA. Your 1 kΩ R3 will limit the current to 5 mA into a dead short. You need to redesign that part of the circuit (and maybe some others).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbbS1A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A possible solution.*

Note that with this arrangement the output will go towards +5 V when the opto-isolator is turned off. This may not be what is required.

Comment: In that case i would invert the logic in coding. Thanks for the tip, I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: Absolute maximum average forward current rating of the optocoupler LED is 25 mA, and CTR might be as low as 25%.

Comment: I just used a simple high-side switch as @ThePhoton suggested

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a low-side switch as @ThePhoton suggested. Worked very well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyAXAW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>